# C++ Macro pasting: is it possible?

Tags: c++, macros

Using QT5 - MinGW:

I'like to write something like:

```
_MyProperty (long,PropertyName);
```

and have it expanded this way:

```
long p_PropertyName;  // this is the private variable
void PropertyName_Get (const long& newVal) {p_PropertyName = newVal;} // setter function
long PropertyName_Set () {return p_PropertyName;} // getter function
__property <MyClass,long,&MyClass::PropertyName_Get,&MyClass::PropertyName_Set> PropertyName;
```

(using the underscore to evidentiate what should be added to the tokens)

I tried with macro pasting etc. but i'm not able to do it.
Is it possible?

Comment: "but i'm not able to do it" show what you have tried and what results/errors you have got.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink and ask yourself if you really need it or if you find a more elegant solution. ;-)

Comment: properties are evil, get-prefixes are verbose noise, macros are evil, names starting with double underscore are reserved to the implementation, names starting with underscore followed by uppercase are reserved to the implementation, member pointers are mostly evil. you **forgot to use goto**.

Comment: Let me just observe here that `_MyProperty` is reserved for use by the compiler (as is any name starting with `_`-capital) and so you really don't know what will happen.

Comment: @n.m. : i'm writing from home now, so tomorrow i'll add my tries. I did'nt 'cause i tought that my approach was wrong and so it had no value.

Comment: @stefan: i really need it 'cause i'm converting, for QT and minGw, some old, well tested and complex classes made in Borland C++Builder 2006 . Being able to have "properties" will make this conversion a lot faster and easier. When the whole thing will run, i will have some breath to optimize it and changing the code is somewhat less IDE-specific, more portable and more elegant.

Comment: @Alf: i may or may not disagree with you, but that's not the point of this question. I asked sometime (maybe in others sites) about what's the best way to do this or that, but now it's not that case. I'd need that old borland code working in "no time", properties in the BDS-style are a way to be faster, so the question is specific.

Answer (score 2):

It should work like this:

```
#define _MyProperty(TYPE,NAME) TYPE p_##NAME; \
void NAME##_Get (const TYPE& newVal) {p_##NAME = newVal;} \
TYPE NAME##_Set () {return p_##NAME;} \
__property <MyClass,TYPE,&MyClass::NAME##_Get,&MyClass::NAME##_Set> NAME;
```

The most important parts:

- The `##` operator glues together parts of a name. You must use it to combine the arguments with other name fragments. If you do not use it and only write `p_NAME`, the lexer would not recognize that `NAME` is a parameter
- You must escape each new line by placing a `\` in front of the line break.